# Correlation functions scale as powers of external momenta

Tags: renormalization

In the 1st paragraph of section 12.2 on page 406 of Peskin and Schroeder, it says "the correlation functions turn out to scale as powers of their external momenta, with power laws that do not appear at any fixed order of perturbation theory."

Before I ask my question, I want to make sure I understand the first part of that sentence. Eqn (12.36) on page 410 is:

$G^{(n)}(x_1, \dots , x_n) = \langle\Omega|T\phi(x_1)\dots\phi(x_n)|\Omega\rangle_{connected}$

where $\phi = Z^{-1/2}\phi_0$ is the renormalized field, and $\phi_0$ is the bare field. eqn (12.35) just above it says:

$\langle\Omega|T\phi(x_1)\dots\phi(x_n)|\Omega\rangle = Z^{-n/2}\langle\Omega|T\phi_0(x_1)\dots\phi_0(x_n)|\Omega\rangle$

Finally, the first unnumbered equation below (12.31) on page 408) gives:

$Z^{-1}\langle\Omega|T\phi(p)\phi(-p)|\Omega\rangle = \frac{i}{p^2}$

Putting all this together for n = 2 I get:

$G^{(2)}(x_1,x_2) \sim \frac{1}{p^2}$

i.e. the correlation function scales as a power (-2) of the external momentum. This equation appears in slightly altered form in eqn (12.67) on page 418. There are other equations which I will not copy from the book where correlation functions appear with factors of powers of the momenta. For example (12.79) on page 421.

This is my interpretation of what the author means by the first part of the quote "correlation functions scale as powers of the momentum." Now for my question. Assuming that my interpretation is correct, what does the author mean by the second part of the quote? "with power laws that do not appear at any fixed order of perturbation theory." Isn't my last equation above a power law that appears at a fixed order of perturbation theory?

Edit:
On page 427 we have eqn (12.97)

$G(p) \approx C \cdot (\frac{1}{p^2})^{1 - \gamma(\lambda_*)}$

It is clear from the surrounding text that by $G$ is meant $G^{(2)}$ so that in comparing two theories, each with a different value of $\gamma(\lambda_*)$, they would have differing power laws for $G^{(2)}$. That's not the same thing as saying a power law does not appear, but even so, it may be what the author meant. What do you think?